# Android : com.android.volley.ServerError

Tags: android, json, server, android-volley, server-error

I am trying to parse volley request as "**JsonObjectRequest**" ,

am getting the error repose as "**com.android.volley.ServerError**" , dont know what the cause.

```
       RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mConetxt);       


JsonObjectRequest putRequestUNregister = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Global.un_register_device, deviceInfoUnRegister,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // response

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    hideProgress();
                    notificationInterface.NotificationReturn(false);
                    Log.e("Error.Response","notify onErrorResponse VolleyError "+ error.toString());
                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        Log.e("Error.Response","notify onErrorResponse VolleyError TimeoutError"+ error.toString());
                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        Log.e("Error.Response","notify onErrorResponse VolleyError AuthFailureError"+ error.toString());
                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        Log.e("Error.Response","notify onErrorResponse VolleyError ServerError"+ error.toString());
                        //TODO
                    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        Log.e("Error.Response","notify onErrorResponse VolleyError NetworkError"+ error.toString());
                        //TODO
                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        Log.e("Error.Response","notify onErrorResponse VolleyError ParseError"+ error.toString());
                        //TODO
                    }
                }
            }
    ) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders()
        {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");

            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {

            try {
                return deviceInfoUnRegister.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

This is the way that am trying to parse, 
and am getting the error as "  **VolleyError com.android.volley.ServerError**"

Comment: Try to make sure your server works well. You can use Postman(chrome plug-in) or any other way to send a post request to the url and see what it responses.

Comment: Try with `StringRequest` and what you got response.

Comment: what you response you are getting....
try to print stackTrace of it

Comment: am getting the response as " VolleyError com.android.volley.ServerError " @ ND1010_

Comment: Please check the **server logs**

Comment: please paste server error code 503 or 500 etc...

Comment: I have the same problem while using imgur api and google url shortener api. The server sometimes returns 500 or 503. But I don't think it's a server problem. Because the error rates of these two api are 10% to 20%. That's too high.

Answer (score 1):

replace code with

```
 headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
 headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
```

to

```
headers.put("Accept","application/json");
headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
```

Comment: can you pls tell me what the response code you are getting?

Comment: its calling new Response.ErrorListener() and the onErrorResponse as "com.android.volley.ServerError" @ND1010_